# Rails Dokku deployments to Digitalocean receives random ports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, dokku

I created a rails app and have successfully deployed it to DigitalOcean. Every time I make a deployment, the port changes. First question, how do I get it to stop, and how do I get my application to respond to port 80 so I can hit it from the outside world without specifying the port number? Part of me wants to go back to heroku and just pay more because I don't get these headaches...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you configure Dokku to use your domain name, it will serve the app at a random port.

Put your root domain name in the file `/home/dokku/VHOST` From [the Dokku docs](http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/installation):

> If this file still is not present when you push your app, dokku will publish the app with a port number (i.e. http://example.com:49154)

Comment: the link to the Dokku Docs is 404. please update if you can! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to enable VHOSTS for my app:

`domains:enable <app>`

See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration/domains/#domain-configuration