# Dokku DigitalOcean Deploy (Cannot access Rails Sample App)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, deployment, digital-ocean, dokku

Trying to deploy an app to DigitalOcean using Dokku

Followed the instructions on: 
 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-dokku-application
then: 
http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/application-deployment

Everything *looked* like it was deploying:
[image: deploy rails app to DigitalOcean using dokku]

```
=====> Application deployed:
       http://178.62.95.224:35954
```

But then when we attempt to navigate to the app in a browser, we cannot access the app on http://178.62.95.224:35954/ 
(*the IP address of the DigitalOcean VM and TCP Port assigned by Dokku*)

What am I doing *wrong*? Do I need to open the TCP port? (*in this case **35954***)
(*read that ports are open by default when ever a service listens on it...
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/opening-ports-on-my-server is this the case?*)

Tried following the suggestion in: [Rails Dokku deployments to Digitalocean receives random ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497928/rails-dokku-deployments-to-digitalocean-receives-random-ports)

```
echo "example.com" > /home/dokku/VHOST
dokku ps:rebuild ruby-rails-sample
```

and

```
dokku config:set ruby-rails-sample DOKKU_NGINX_PORT=80
```

but no luck!
[image: still get port]

Comment: try adding another port here
dokku config:set ruby-rails-sample DOKKU_NGINX_PORT=3450
normally, port 80 didn't work for me neither, but another one does. and then rebuild or restart the server

Comment: @xploshioOn thanks _very_ much for the tip. tried it and the dokku server just keeps defaulting to the existing port.

Comment: note-to-self: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573668/best-practices-when-running-node-js-with-port-80-ubuntu-linode (this totally worked!)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to turn off `ufw` so that the random port is exposed to the world. You can get around this by instead using subdomains for virtualhosts.

Comment: rather than _disabling_ the firewall, I opened the specific port `sudo ufw allow 35954/tcp`